# Android parse throws IllegalStateException. Need directions for debugging

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm developing an Android app using `Parse` for backend. Things were working just fine until a weird crash started showing up. I've pasted the stack trace below. 
Can anyone help find out what the actual cause is? 
My research says it's because of large strings in database columns. But i had large strings since the beginning in my `ParseObject`s without any issues.

Code:

```
private HashMap getFormResponsesMap() {
        HashMap<String, FormResponse> formResponsesMap = new HashMap<>();
        ParseQuery<FormResponse> query = FormResponse.getQuery();
        query.fromPin(Application.FORM_RESPONSE_GROUP_NAME);
        query.whereEqualTo("surveyor", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        query.fromLocalDatastore();
        try {
            List<FormResponse> objects = query.find(); //exception is thrown here.
            for (FormResponse response : objects) {
                formResponsesMap.put(response.getUuidString(), response);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return formResponsesMap;
}
```

Stack trace:

```
11-24 22:36:45.913 22779-23746/com.myapp.qa E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-26505
Process: com.myapp.qa, PID: 22779
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
at com.parse.OfflineStore$9.then(OfflineStore.java:607)
at com.parse.OfflineStore$9.then(OfflineStore.java:590)
at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:872)
at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
at bolts.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:863)
at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:661)
at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:672)
at bolts.Task$12.then(Task.java:766)
at bolts.Task$12.then(Task.java:754)
at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:917)
at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:908)
at bolts.Task.access$100(Task.java:32)
at bolts.Task$11.then(Task.java:708)
at bolts.Task$11.then(Task.java:705)
at bolts.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:956)
at bolts.Task.trySetResult(Task.java:994)
at bolts.TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(TaskCompletionSource.java:39)
at bolts.TaskCompletionSource.setResult(TaskCompletionSource.java:62)
at bolts.Task$15$1.then(Task.java:934)
at bolts.Task$15$1.then(Task.java:921)
at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:872)
at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
at bolts.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:863)
at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:661)
at bolts.Task.continueWith(Task.java:672)
at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:921)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: what happens if you try without the query.fromLocalDatastore();

Comment: @mogile_oli thanks, the issue doesn't show up all the time but will try the change you mentioned. Is there specific reason this change might fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is too late to answer this question but for future readers, 
One of the reasons why this happens is when you try to access the value of a column from the cursor where that column does not exist. 
Which means either table name or column name is incorrect.